# contar las instancias por FK

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Buen dia perdon por la consulta, soy un poco nuevo y lento den django, el asunto es que estoy creando una app para asistencia en donde el catedratico crea la leccion y el usuario crea una asistencia, la asistencia esta relacionada al la leccion por una FK necesito contar cuantas asistencias han sido creadas para finalizar mi leccion y guardar el numero de instancias creadas referentes a esa leccion. Espero me puedan apoyor, por cierto estoy trabajando en el Admin de django. dejo mis clases.

```
# Models.py
# Metodo para generar el Key
def get_rand_string():
    """Devuelve un string de 20 caracteres aleatorios"""
    return ''.join(random.choice(
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy' +
        'z0123456789') for i in
        range(8))


class Leccion(models.Model):
    seccion = models.ForeignKey(
        Seccion, verbose_name='Curso', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField('Fecha', auto_now_add=True)
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name='Código',
        default=get_rand_string)
    asistencias = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=0, verbose_name='Alumnos contados')
    done = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Finalizada', default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Clase"
        verbose_name_plural = "Clases"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seccion.curso.nombre


class Asistencia(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, verbose_name='Estudiante', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leccion = models.ForeignKey(
        Leccion, verbose_name='curso', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name='codigo')
    time = models.TimeField('Hora', auto_now_add=True)
    correcto = models.BooleanField(
        'Asistio', help_text='Recibio el 80% del Curso')
    permiso = models.BooleanField(
        'Permiso', help_text='Solicito permiso para no asister o ausentarse')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Asistencia"
        verbose_name_plural = "Asistencias"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def clean(self):
        super(Asistencia, self).clean()
        if not (self.key):
            raise ValidationError('Tienes que ingresar el código para' +
                                  'validar tu Asistencia')
        if self.key:
            if self.key != self.key:
                raise ValidationError('Ese código no se corresponde con el ' +
                                      'de la clase actual')

    def conteo(self):
        n = Asistencia.objects.filter(id=self.leccion.id).count()
        return n

    # Admin.py
     class AsistenciaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['conteo']


class AsistenciaInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Asistencia
    verbose_name_plural = 'Registro de Asistencias'
    min_num = 0
    extra = 0


class LeccionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = []
    readonly_fields = ['key', 'asistencias']
    inlines = [AsistenciaInline]
    list_display = ['seccion', 'date', 'done']


admin.site.register(Leccion, LeccionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Asistencia, AsistenciaAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una versión resumida de tu código con las líneas agregadas y modificadas. Básicamente añadí el atributo `related_name` a la relación `leccion` del modelo `Asistencia`, y en el admin agregué una columna con el total de asistencia de cada lección.

```py
class Asistencia(models.Model):
    leccion = models.ForeignKey(Leccion, verbose_name='curso', related_name='asistencias', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class LeccionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['seccion', 'date', 'done', 'total_asistencia']

    def total_asistencia(self, obj):
        return obj.asistencias.count()

    total_asistencia.short_description = 'total asistencia'
```